# Why getting error for this very simple class?

Tags: python

I am learning classes in python. I do not know why I get error for this very simple class. Where I am doing wrong?

```
class Human: 
    def __int__(self, name, age):
        self.Name= name
        self.Age= age


jeff= Human('Jeff', 19)
print(jeff.Name)
print(jeff.Age)
```

Why it says Human() takes no arguments, while I defined Name and Age for it?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-aecee9dc95ca> in <module>
      5 
      6 
----> 7 jeff= Human('Jeff', 19)
      8 print(jeff.Name)
      9 print(jeff.Age)

TypeError: Human() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning `__int__` to `__init__`.

Comment: still does not work. get error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I don't get it. this code should work. I see no problem in it. But get error.

Comment: @Ali.A you would need to update the question (or perhaps better since it would invalidate existing answers, ask a new question) with the updated code and the new error. But this kind of pure programming question belongs at stackoverflow rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

You put three underscores around init. Should be two.

Comment: Firstly, you are right. Thanks for mentioning it. But by correcting it, still get same error.